How to convert pcapng file to csv with pyshark
I want to convert multiple pcapng files to csv using python. Is it possible with pyshark because I was not able to find any documentation regarding it
I tried scapy and pyshark by appending the captured values to a dataframe but the output came to be null
for packet in capture:
        # Extract necessary fields from each packet and append to the data list
        time = packet.sniff_time.timestamp
        if time is not None and isinstance(time, (int, float, str)):  # Check if the timestamp is valid
            time = float(time)
        else:
            continue

        if 'IP' not in packet:  # Skip non-IP packets
            continue

        src = packet['ip'].src
        dst = packet['ip'].dst
        proto = packet['ip'].proto
        length = int(packet.length)
        info = ''
        try:
            if 'DATA' in packet and hasattr(packet, 'data'):
                info = packet.data.data_raw.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass

        data.append((time, src, dst, proto, length, info))


I don't think it is possible to covert an entire capture to a CSV file.  It is possible to extract specific data points from your pcap and write them to a CSV.   Here is a my GitHub repository on how to extract packet data using PyShark.  Take a look at my examples.  If you have any questions please let me know.

If you're troubleshooting why something doesn't work, put print statements in areas that might be the cause. The two continue statements need a print above them.
Same for the try/except block. You won't know what happens if you let the exception pass silently.
The slightly adjusted code below shows why some packets are failing, and with the print statements I was able to determine that you missed the brackets on the line to get the time from the packet.
NOTE
Instead of re-inventing the wheel, you might want to look at an existing package and just use that (google shows this one for example:  pcap-handler
(note that I'm using a list instead of a df, but in this case that's not a problem)
import pyshark
from pprint import pprint

capture = pyshark.FileCapture('sample.pcapng')
data = []

for packet in capture:
        # Extract necessary fields from each packet and append to the data list
        time = packet.sniff_time.timestamp() # <== this was the main issue
        # Check if the timestamp is valid
        if time is not None and isinstance(time, (int, float, str)):
            time = float(time)
        else:
            print(f"no time on packet:\n{packet}")
            continue

        if 'IP' not in packet:  # Skip non-IP packets
            print(f"no IP on packet:\n{packet}")
            continue

        src = packet['ip'].src
        dst = packet['ip'].dst
        proto = packet['ip'].proto
        length = int(packet.length)
        info = ''
        try:
            if 'DATA' in packet and hasattr(packet, 'data'):
                info = packet.data.data_raw.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print(f"UnicodeDecodeError on packet:\n{packet}")
        except AttributeError:
            print(f"AttributeError on packet:\n{packet}")

        data.append((time, src, dst, proto, length, info))

pprint(data, indent=4)

